# BizTalk - create log file for pipeline fault

Tags: biztalk, fault, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-pipelines

I need to handle an application for the 2006 version.

Starting with this version, BizTalk can route fault messages, and that's pretty good. Let's say I'm receiving a badly-formatted positional txt file and a receive pipeline can't let the message get into the orchestration. I can see that between the 'Suspended Services Instances' I have my suspended service gone in error with its code and its pretty explicit description.

I would love to get all this data into a file (txt, xml, whatever) and route it into a dedicate folder, without using custom pipeline components or other libraries, just BizTalk out of the box functionalities.

Is it all possible?

[image: This is the error I would love to capture, together with the body of the message, if possible]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you set up Failed Message Routing on this receive port, you can create a filter subscription in another FILE send port for **ErrorReport.ErrorType == "FailedMessage"**. This send port can save the error report and the original message out to a file.

Alternatively, you can have an orchestration subscribe to these failed messages if you want to do any further processing with them (e.g. logging of the error details).

See [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/nsthompson/archive/2006/10/11/BTS2K6_FailedMessageRouting.aspx) for some help with that, or view the official MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578516.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you for answering, i really appreciate it.

Comment: i tried it and i only obtain the original message, which is good but is half of what i wanted. I'm not sure ho to get the error message as well, though

Comment: You might need an orchestration then to subscribe to the failed message. Then you could extract the details out of the message context and write them where you want to. You could also do this (more efficiently) in a custom pipeline component... but I'm aware that you wanted to avoid this in your original post.

Comment: He @DanToomey can you Please provide Example of any that handle this error as we are also facing same Issue

Comment: Hi @Hardik. I don't have a working example to share as I haven't worked with BizTalk for quite some time. However this documentation page should help with identifying the solution.  As stated in my last comment, if you create an orchstration to subscribe to the failed message (the article will tell you how, just include filter ErrorType=="FailedMessage" and InboundTransportLocation=<recLocnName>), you can then extract the error details from the context properties. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/using-failed-message-routing

Answer (score 0):

For later versions of BizTalk (Enterprise edition) you can install the ESB Toolkit and set up the [The ESB Management Portal and Fault Message Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250068(v=bts.10).aspx).  This includes a BizTalk application that subscribes to failed messages and writes them to a databse where you can view both the message, the context properties of the message and the errors.